# Why can't I use more than 3 variables in my assembly code?

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

I'm starting with assembly, specially with GNU assembly, so I'm playing with registers, variables and values and that kind of stuff, but then I noticed that I can't use more than 3 variables. First I wrote this:

```
    .section .data
    chars:  .ascii "something"
    stuff:  .long 0
    more:   .long 1

    .section .text
    .globl _start

    _start:
        movl stuff, %eax
        movl %eax, stuff

        movl $1, %eax
        movl $0, %ebx
        int $0x80
```

and tried it on the terminal and worked, but then I tried this

```
.section .data
chars:  .ascii "something"
stuff:  .long 0
more:   .long 1
evenmore:   .long 3

.section .text
.globl _start

_start:
    movl stuff, %eax
    movl %eax, stuff

    movl $1, %eax
    movl $0, %ebx
    int $0x80
```

and this didn't work. I got a Segmentation fault error.
What could be wrong? What should I do?

Comment: @Dor The full error message for a segmentation fault is "Segmentation fault".

Comment: tried running it through a debugger?

Comment: @Necrolis Yes sir, already tried with gdb and got not too much information:

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
_start () at mov.s:12
12  movl %eax, stuff

Comment: Is this on Linux or FreeBSD or something else?

Comment: @Alex GNU/Linux Ubuntu 11.10 3.0.0-16

Comment: Are you sure the above is the code that you've compiled? How did you compile it? Can you show the disassembly of the two versions?

Comment: start by learning the x86 instruction set, disassemble some C or other programs to see what is going on, etc.  x86 is the worst first assembly language to learn btw, there are many better ones to learn first (you dont need/want the hardware to learn them).

Comment: Not having any problems running the second example.

Comment: @Alex I dont know I dont tried without gcc, I was doing this 'gcc -nostartfiles myfile.asm', thank you all

Comment: Btw, How do I mark this as solved?, it's my first question around here.

Comment: If someone answered and it solved the problem, you mark their answer as the answer. If the answer was in a comment, you can ask the person to repost it as an answer and then you mark it. If you yourself find the answer, you can post it as the answer and mark it.

Comment: you should move the longs to the section start to make sure that it's properly aligned. In x86 unaligned access works but more slowly

Answer (score 2):

It was a problem while compiling, so I changed the '_start' with 'main' and then used gcc, it was as simple as that.

Before this I was trying with gcc, using the -nostartfiles option, also tried using as and ld, there should be a way this to work with that but using gcc and changing '_start' with 'main' was the easiest and fastest I could do.